# Is there a way to add an empty element to a list in OCaml?

Tags: ocaml

Consider a given list `[3;4;5]`.
Now, I want to execute `x::[3;4;5];;`
Is there an `x` in OCaml which leads to the result `[3;4;5]` again?

Comment: Could append to an empty list vs a list with one time. Changes the question constraints entirely though.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The other answers are also correct, but I thought it might be helpful to take a look at how `list` is defined.

Under the hood, `list` roughly looks like the following:

```
type 'a list =
  | []
  | ( :: ) of 'a * 'a list
```

This implies two things:

1. `( :: )` will always prepend an element to an existing list.
2. The elements of the list must be of the same type.

So if you have a list `[3; 4; 5]` already, then `x` must be an `int` for `x :: [3; 4; 5]` to compile.

Comment: Wouldn't you want to prepend instead of appending?

Comment: @lambda.xy.x Yep, I think what I meant to say was "append to the front of the list", since appending to the back is O(n), but "prepend" is unambiguous, so I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 7):

No, the result of `x::xs` is always going to be a list that has one element more than `xs` does.

If you want to prepend an element to a list conditionally, you'll have to do `if condition then x::xs else xs`. That is, only use `::` in the case where you actually have an element you want to prepend.

Answer (score 2):

No, `::` always creates a new list that is one element longer.

What you might be looking for is `@` which appends one list to another (actually it prepends the first list before the second). For that you have `[] @ list ==> list`.

Answer (score 1):

No they can never be equal - the first one is a list of length 3, the other one is a list of length 4.